# Size of the NSMutable Array in objective C?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want to ask the size of the NSMutable Array can be 2000? If not, is it possible to open an array to store 2000 elements. The elements is the user-defined object. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that an NSMutableArray always starts with a size of zero.  If you want it to be so you can do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray* anArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithSize: 2000];
[anArray replaceObjectAtIndex: 1999 withObject: foo];
```

you need to prefill the array with NSNull objects e.g.

```
@implementation NSArray(MyArrayCategory)

+(NSMutableArray*) arrayWithSize: (NSUInteger) size
{
    NSMutableArray* ret = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: size];
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
    {
        [ret addObject: [NSNull null]];
    }
    return [ret autorelease];
}

@end
```

Edit: some further clarification:

`-initWithCapacity:` provides a hint to the run time about how big you think the array might be.  The run time is under no obligation to actually allocate that amount of memory straight away.

```
    NSMutableArray* foo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 1000000];
    NSLog(@"foo count = %ld", (long) [foo count]);
```

will log a count of 0.

`-initWithCapacity:` does not limit the size of an array:

```
    NSMutableArray* foo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 1];
    [foo addObject: @"one"];
    [foo addObject: @"two"];
```

doesn't cause an error.

Comment: thank you for your reply. And I have a question about your explanation. Is all the NSMutableArray in the objective-c is size of 0 in the begining?

Comment: Yes if you do `[[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 100000] count]` you will get the answer 0.